# Getting Background Resource in another class in Android

Tags: android, android-resources, ontouchlistener

I have quite a number of Buttons in an Android application and I want a separate class to be created to handle the Touch events.

So I created the following class:

```
public class OnTouchButtonEffects implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)                        
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonbluepress);
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
    }
}
```

Now I want that if `view v` has `event ACTION_DOWN` then I get the background resource and append "press" to it and then set that as background resource and if it's `event ACTION_UP` then get background resource and remove "press" from the resource name and set it as its new background resource.

I tried using `getResources()` but couldn't figure out how exactly that be done.

So the problem is how do I get the name of the background resource, and append/remove from its name.

Comment: use `setTag` and `getTag` methods for saving or getting background resource id of View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can work with Resource addresses (i.e., R.id.nameOfResourse) the way you're asking.

I see what you're attempting to accomplish, and there is a much easier way to use customized buttons:

StateListDrawable http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/buttonbluepress" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/buttonblue" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/buttonblue" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonblue" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Resources` class has this method:

```
public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

So you can get the id of a resource by its name. When you got the id you can set the background.

If you want to know the resource name from the id use:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

or

```
getResources().getResourceName(int resid);
```

You should be able to combine both methods to achieve what you need.